# Integrating Parse SDK with React Native App

Tags: parse-platform, react-native

Are there any advantages of using the JS/Node Parse SDK with React Native instead of the IOS Parse SDK?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react native, you can only use JS/Node Parse SDk since IOS thread only provide UI and logic should be in javascript thread. So your question seems the advantage of React native development than IOS native development. You can get this from react native site:

> React Native enables you to build world-class application experiences
>   on native platforms using a consistent developer experience based on
>   JavaScript and React. The focus of React Native is on developer
>   efficiency across all the platforms you care about — learn once, write
>   anywhere.

Comment: From what I read on the site and other resources, there is a separate thread that renders the UI using native components while the main thread is free to respond to user input. This does not imply you will not write native code. In fact, you still have to expose some features (e.g. camera) that are not inherently supported by react native by using their RTCBridgeModule. It seems like overkill to do this for Parse but if I want to cache data locally on the device or use native features I will still have to bridge the required components to make them available in JS.

Comment: Anyhow, I will evaluate https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact and the JS SDK first.

Comment: BTW, "you can only use JS/Node Parse SDk" is not correct. I integrated an npm module and tried the following as well: http://brentvatne.ca/facebook-login-with-react-native/. Both solutions exposed the native components to the JS runtime. Again this seems like overkill but there isnt much material comparing the experience using either SDK.